# How can I get around the fact that my domain registrar isn't working?

Tags: domain-name-system

All my websites are down right now. My domain registrar's site is also down periodically (mydomain.com).

I think I could probably get around the fact that my domains aren't working by getting somebody else to point a subdomain at the IP for one of my servers. But I don't know the IP for any of my servers because none of their domains are working.

Can anyone think of a way to find out what my server's IP WAS? Any other ideas for getting around this problem?

Comment: If your server sends email, and you have ever sent yourself an email from it, the IP address should be in the email headers.

Comment: Registrars do not host your domains, a DNS host does. It's possible (likely in this case) that they do both of those for you, but it's not the same thing. A registrar going down or even out of business has little effect on your daily operations. You need to figure out exactly what part of the system is breaking down and build redundancy into that. If it's DNS hosting then there are free backup DNS providers that will mitigate the problem quickly (though a good DNS host would already have geographically diverse systems).

Comment: Transfer your domain to a Registrar that will also host the DNS, but won't have the issues that your current Registrar is having. Yes, they can all have issues (and have in the past) but I've found Network Solutions to be incredibly reliable over the years.

Answer (score 2):

Grubbing around in old log files and DNS caches is probably your best bet if the delegated DNS servers for your domain aren't answering queries. You may find that some of the "DNS tools" type web sites also have some cached information that can help you out.